# Installing IIS on MS Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis

I have a Windows Server 2003 and asp.net website running on localhost. I have to install php and mysql, but php installation doesn't work for whatever reason. I was wondering if I could install package such as xampp on windows server to save time and hassle installing in manually (I could not find a tutorial for this). I was wondering though, if it is safe, i.e. what will happen if I go to http://localhost/ - will I get the php or asp website? In general, is it safe to install xampp on windows server 2003? All advice greatly appreciated

Comment: I cannot answer your question about xampp, but how much time have you spent working on php. There are plenty of sites running on Windows that use php, I am surprised you haven't posted your php error on here to see if people can help you with that as well?

Answer (score 0):

As asp.net website is already running, as you told, IIS is also already installed. If you want to run php files, you could install xampp or other equivalent AMP installation (i.e. EasyPHP) but you have to consider some config stuff to do. In your example, http://localhost will serve a asp page, because IIS was the first to be installed, so it takes the default http port 80.

On the other hand, you have to change your apache config in order to serve another free port (i.e. 8080). In this way to access php website you'll go to localhost:8080.